# Can't change border radius of text-field variant=filled in Material-ui-core

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

### Current Behavior

my current component is as follows

```
export const BirthdayTextFields = styled(TextField)`
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
`;
```

and I'm using it as follows:

```
<BirthdayTextFields
                      id="filled-dense-hidden-label"
                      margin="dense"
                      hiddenLabel
                      variant="filled"
                      placeholder="18"
                      inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'dense hidden label' }}
                      onChange={this.handleChange('day')}
                    />
```

since the variant="failed" it doesn't allow me to set the border-radius, I have tried overriding the rule fo TextField Component by following trick:

```
export const TextFieldWrapper = styled(TextField)`
  fieldset {
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
`;
```

and I'm using like this, since it is variant=outlined the overriding works

```
<TextFieldWrapper
                  id="outlined-dense"
                  label="Last name"
                  margin="dense"
                  variant="outlined"
                  onChange={this.handleChange('lastName')}
                />
```

So how to solve this out? I have also try adding the fieldset value to BirthdayTextFields but it doesn't make any effect mostly becaues of the variant="filled"

```js
export const BirthdayTextFields = styled(TextField)`
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  fieldset {
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
`;
```

### Environment

Windows 10

Tech : Version

Material-UI:  ^3.9.3

React : ^16.8.6

Browser : Chrome

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `<FilledInput>` ?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    borderRadius: "50px 50px 0 0"
  },
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
  }
}));

export default function FilledTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    name: "Cat in the Hat",
    age: "",
    multiline: "Controlled",
    currency: "EUR"
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <FilledInput
        id="filled-name"
        label="Name"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={values.name}
        onChange={handleChange("name")}
        margin="normal"
        variant="filled"
        classes={{
          root: classes.root
        }}
      />
    </form>
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-sos7s

Comment: Haven't tried this approach because I didn't know classes can be used like this, 
Is there any way that I can just write it in styled-components way? Otherwise I will write all the css just like how you showed here

Comment: I have tried adding the makeStyles logic in that styles.js file but since it doesn't get called it gives an error saying 
```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module.componentsSignInStyleJs (webpack:///components/SignIn/style.js:52:1)
 
```

also the components are mostly class based and not functional component so its a little tough for me to convert them into functional component to have it execute the same functionality.

Comment: `makeStyles` is a V4 feature of material UI. If you are on a lower version you could wrap it in a `withStyles` HOC instead. That will work fine for class based components and functional components.

https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/

Comment: I am looking at this approach : https://codesandbox.io/s/skrw9 with `withStyles` but the problem is the TextField is just one thing inside my big component and that is also wrapped around `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignIn);` so should I wrap that whole statement with the `withStyle(styleObject)(MyReduxComponent)` ?

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to access the outline container which applies the borderRadius, so I used the CSS approach instead.

```
<TextField className="inputRounded" placeholder="Search" variant="outlined" />
```

Then I addeded the the borderRadius code in the index.css file of the project.

```
.inputRounded .MuiOutlinedInput-root{
   border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root':{borderRadius:10}

Answer (score 2):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
   root: {
      [`& fieldset`]: {
            borderRadius: 15,
      },
   },
});

<TextField
  className={classes.root}
  id="inputRounded"
  label="Email address"
  variant="outlined"
  fullWidth
/>
```

Comment: This is when we know that TextField actually renders the fieldset inside the DOM. This approach is more like knowing an internal class that is being rendered in one of the child elements. Really good and quick workaround. Can't be duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the browser dev tools to identify the slot for the component you want to override.
Once that's done, you write a CSS file with the class you want to change.

To force the class you can use :

!important

file : styles.css

```
.css-1q6at85-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root{
    border-radius: 50px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in a clear way, it worked for me
add this to sx={} in TextField

```
 '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
   '& fieldset': {
     borderColor: 'black',
     borderRadius: 2,
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CreateTheme and edit shape.borderRadius from "4" default to "0"

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material' 
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'

const el = document.getElementById('root')
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(el)

const theme = createTheme({
   shape: {
      borderRadius: 0,
   },
})

console.log(theme)
root.render(
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
   </ThemeProvider>
)
```